# How to get a Google spreadsheet cell to display a number as 4 digits, even if it's less than that

Tags: google-sheets

This is a formatting issue. Basically, I would like to get all the numbers I enter into a column become 4 digits in the other column ("output column"), with 0's in front as applicable.

E.g. when I enter 16, I want the output cell to be `0016`. What formula can I use for this?

Answer (score 7):

Enter a Custom Cell format and specify it as "0000" (without the quotes.)

1. right click a cell and pick "format"
2. click the last item in the list "custom"
3. Click in the "type" box click and type 0000 after removing anything that is already in the "type" box.

Comment: brilliant! works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Using two columns, you can do this:

```
=TEXT(A1,"0000")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Copy from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24966144/1505120) with one fewer zero:

```
=ArrayFormula(text(A1:A,"0000"))
```